# Tree : Forest :: Path :?

Tags: graphs, terminology

A forest is a collection of trees.

Is there a similar notion for paths? e.g., a ***_*__*_*__*_*** is a collection of paths.

Comment: Not that I know of. You can call it a "path forest".

Comment: I haven't heard of a suitable term either. Just to speculate wildly, I conjecture that it's because "tree" and "path" do not refer to the same sort of object. A tree is a type of graph (connected acyclic) and a forest is where we drop the acyclic part. A path, at the basic level, is a sort-of-ordered subset of the vertices/edges (depending on how you want to define it) of a graph, and we just overload the term to mean a graph that doesn't have any other vertices or edges either. Then with this view there's no "collection of paths", and by inertia we haven't created one since.

Comment: @LukeMathieson I don't buy your argument that a path isn't a "real" graph at all. Paths are perfectly good graphs in their own right; the fact that their structure is so simple that they can be uniquely specified by listing their vertices in order doesn't affect that.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, I wasn't saying that they're not "real" graphs, I was _speculating wildly_ about the historical reason we don't seem to have a neat, widely known term for disjoint union of paths.

Comment: @LukeMathieson: You probably also meant that a forest is where you drop the condition of being *connected*. In any case, even if there are historical reasons why collections of paths were not given a name, surely by the time people started studying path covers this should not longer have been true. One could just as easily ask: `Spanning Forest : Path cover :: Forest : ?`

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap, yes, drop connected (wouldn't it be nice if fingers and brain actually communicated ;) ). Also, I think it is a good question to ask, it just doesn't seem to have an intellectually satisfying answer, linear forest &c is fine, but it doesn't have the same nice ring as tree & forest. Maybe it's just that no one has thought of a good pun.

Comment: @Austin Buchanan Are you interested only in terminology for basic graph theory, or are you also interested in terminology and use of the concepts in a more general context?

Comment: @babou graph theory. what did you have in mind?

Comment: @AustinBuchanan When you start labeling the graphs, or orienting the edges, or choosing roots for the trees, you get all kinds of new concepts, where trees, forest and paths take new meanings, and may have specific names. But I was afraid it might be considered off topic, given your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29#Types_of_trees) says that a graph all of whose non-trivial components are paths is a **linear forest**. Alternatively, you could call it just a **disjoint union of paths**.